# Mocking exceptions with Mockito: Unexpected Exception error

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

This is the code of my service:

```
public class Service {
   public Object serviceMethod() throws MyException {
      @Autowired
      Dao dao;

      try {
         return dao.dao_method();
      } catch (ExceptionFromDaoMethod e) {
         throw (new MyException());
      }
   }
}
```

I want to write a simple Unit Test; this is my test case:

```
@Mock
Dao dao;

@InjectMocks
Service service;

@Test(expected=MyException.class)
public void shouldReturnMyException throws MyException {
   when(service.serviceMethod()).thenThrow(new MyException());
}
```

This test fails, because I have an Unexpected exception:

> the expected exception is MyException but was
>   org.mockito.exception.base.MockitoException

Why? What is the solution?

**Update**
Thanks to @Maciej Kowalski I have noted that I was using the *when* condition versus a real class and not versus a mocked one. 
So I added the annotation `@Spy` to the Service in the Unit Test.
 The code of the new test is:

```
@Mock
Dao dao;

@InjectMocks
@Spy
Service service;

@Before
MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

@Test(expected=MyException.class)
public void shouldReturnMyException throws MyException {
   doThrow(new MyException()).when(service.serviceMethod());
}
```

But now I have this problem:

> the expected exception is MyException but was

Answer (score 2):

You would have to @spy the Service as i assume you are using it as the instance with real implementation being invoked.

So try this:

```
@InjectMocks
@Spy
Service service;

@Test(expected=MyException.class)
public void shouldReturnMyException throws MyException {
   doThrow(new MyException()).when(service).serviceMethod();
}
```

remember to start with doXX when mocking a @Spy.

**Update**

If you want to mock the dao call (which is a better test candidate..) you would have to make some changes if you only want to use plain Mockito.

If the dao is not your instance dependency then you will have to change your prod method:

```
public class Service {
   public Object serviceMethod() throws MyException {
      Dao dao = getDaoInstance();
      try {
         return dao.dao_method();
      } catch (ExceptionFromDaoMethod e) {
         throw (new MyException());
      }
   }

   Dao getDaoInstance(){
      return new Dao();
   }
}
```

And your test class should me more or less like this:

```
@Mock
Dao dao;

@Spy
Service service;

@Test(expected=MyException.class)
public void shouldReturnMyException throws MyException {
   doReturn(dao).when(service).getDaoInstance();

   when(dao.dao_method()).thenThrow(new ExceptionFromDaoMethod());

   service.serviceMethod();
}
```

Comment: Could you explain me why my solution is wrong? Furthermore, in your soluton it is when(service.serviceMethod()) or when(service).serviceMethod()?

Comment: Now the unexpected exception is expected MyException but was <org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException>

Comment: You were trying to mock an instance which is not a Mock or as Spy so doing that will have not impact or will raise a Mockito exception.  And yes when you mock the a method of a spy you use .when(service).serviceMethod();' syntax.

Comment: have you annotated your class with @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) or added this method? @Before
 public void init(){
  MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); 
 }

Comment: I have inserted in @Before public void init() {MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)}. Same result

Comment: PS: I use Spring Framework, so I have annotated my class with @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)

Comment: just to be clear.. there is nothing more you do in that test except that one line right?

Comment: dont forget that you actally have to run the method to get the exceptoin.. service.serviceMethod()

Comment: So it is not necessary also @Mock Dao dao? I'm confused

Comment: ok i get you now.. tell me.. do you have to create the instance inside the mehthod Dao dao = new Dao();? or are possibly planning to inject it into the class?

Comment: I want to inject Dao, see my first post. What do you mean when you say "dont forget that you actually have to run the method"?

Comment: if you create the dao instance inside of you serviceMethod then using Mock and InjectMock is useless..

Comment: I don't understand...just to be clear, I have a service and the Dao class is a dependency for the service. I want to test the service, so I want to mock the dependency.

Comment: ok.. so this code: Dao dao = new Dao();.. is not in your prod method in that case? If it is a dependency then 'dao' should be an instance variable right?

Comment: yes, in the class service that I want to test there is, obviously, the code Dao dao = new Dao()  (see my first post). I edit my question using @Autowired spring annotation

Comment: I have updated my question because I'm confused....I don't understand what is the difference in your solution using the getDaoInstance()

Comment: hehe.. you cant seem to make your mind. Again if you create an instance inside the method under test.. Mockito will not know about it because it will not create it.. you will manually.. you can only use inject Mocks using annotations on instance field dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution: create unit tests for a Spring project is more challenging than I expected (at least using only Mockito Framework), so I found a solution using also some Spring Annotations

So this is my new working test:

```
@MockBean
Dao dao;

@Autowired
Service service;

@Test(expected=MyException.class)
public void shouldReturnMyException throws MyException {
   when(dao.dao_method()).thenThrow(new ExceptionFromDaoMethod());
}
```